# How can I stop and continue a function with buttons?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, clearinterval

I am pretty new to javascript. So sorry if this is a stupid question.I'm trying to loop a function until I click on a button but, after my function stopped once, it never stops again.

```
$(start)
function myFunc() //start function
{
var u = 0
var myVar = setInterval(funcc,1000)
function funcc () 
    {         
    //function that I need to loop//   
    //Stuff//    
if ( u === 1)
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
$(Stop)
function myFuncx () //stop function
    {
        u = 1;        
    }
}
```

I expect, when I click on Start button, function ButtonClickAction runs every 1 sec, and when I click on stop button it stops.
ex:

```
//click start => runs every 1 sec
//click stop => stops
//click start => runs every 1 sec
//click stop => stops
```

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you run the code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode), do you get any errors, like "assignment to undeclared variable" on the console?

Comment: No, I dont get any errors.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/itevarukuc.js this is my code and i'm trying to use it on tampermonkey for some website